# Show 2D point cloud in PCL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, bitmap, mfc, point-cloud-library

I have a 3D point cloud representing a sewer. What I need is to convert this 3D into 2D using [cavalier projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_projection#Cavalier_projection) and once done that show the 2D representation. Each point represent a place inside a sewer. I mean, a laser was used to detect the sewer and several points (6470) were produced during the scan of the sewer.

I have converted them into 2D and stored into a vector of pairs of double.  What I want now is to show them into my MFC application, maybe using a bitmap.

I don't know if using a vector of pair of doubles is the best option or if a bitmap is the way to achieve this problem. Any kind of suggestion will be helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: What's your purpose here and what does each point represent?

Comment: @Dexter I have a 3D point cloud representing a sewer. What I need is to convert this 3D into 2D using cavalier projections: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_projection#Cavalier_projections and once done that show the 2D representation.

Each point represent a place inside a sewer. I mean, a laser was used to detect the sewer and several points (6470) were produced during the scan of the sewer.

Comment: @avm_69 don't post tons of informatino in comments but update your question.

Comment: I'm unclear what the question is here - are you asking how to draw a 2d graphic? You have your coordinates projected, all you need now is to use a graphics api to show them on the screen. You can use GDI/GDI+, a portable API like Cairo, or DirectX/OpenGL. Or another library like SDL. You have many options. The simplest way is to derive a control from CWnd, implement OnPaint, rescale your coordinates to fit within the control and use CDC::SetPixel. It's also by far the slowest method.